# Compiler error "Incorrect number of type arguments to local call"

Tags: f#

I'm running into the compiler error "Incorrect number of type arguments to local call" when using custom types with unit-of-measure type arguments, and I do not understand why.

*This question has undergone quite a few edits. It looks likely now that the error is caused by a compiler or IDE bug.*

I could narrow it down to the following **(read the points below when trying to reproduce)**:

```
type R<[<Measure>] 'u> (f : float<'u>) =
    member r.Member = f

let get (r : R<_>) = r.Member
let foo =
    let problem _ = List.map get
    problem // Error: Incorrect number of type arguments to local call
```

The last line gives the error, which is especially weird, since it is doing nothing more than returning an already-defined identifier. I am compiling to a library or executable. Some important observations for reproduction:

- IntelliSense does *not* predict this error. An actual compilation is required to see it.
- I haven't yet seen the error when compiling with optimization. (For reproduction, use e.g. the default debug compile in Visual Studio. Thanks to zapu on Freenode for pointing this out.)
- I haven't yet seen the error in F# interactive.
- Removing the useless parameter of `problem` (the `_`) makes the error disappear.
- Moving the let-binding of `problem` out of `foo` makes the error disappear. *Might this be related to compilation as an F# function? I heard that this is indicated by additional parentheses around the type of* `problem`.
- Removing the unit-of-measure usage makes the error disappear.
- Marking `problem` as `inline` makes the error disappear.

A lot of seemingly irrelevant changes remove the error. But it isn't that easy in the actual use case, especially when I don't know whether a change fixes the error before I try it.

I'd be happy about any hints on this. What causes it? Is it a bug, and if so, is it known? How can it be avoided?

**Versions** This was tested with versions from 3.0 to 3.1.2 of F#. I installed the new Visual Studio 2013 Community edition and tested with the version it supplied, with the same result. It also occurs in Visual Studio 2012 (F# 3.0).

Update: I've asked others to test this, and the behavior can often be reproduced in Visual Studio 2012 or 2013.

Comment: No compiler error for me, but the `problem _` syntax seems extremely odd, I am not qutie sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JohnPalmer I was just trying to reproduce the error without copying the much larger code that causes it in production, and this was the result. I removed the mention of version 3.1.1. from the question though; I might have unknowingly been using the 3.0 compiler. I'm trying to figure out what is going on right now, and I'll update the question if I find out something. Maybe I've foolishly run into an already-fixed bug.

Comment: @JohnPalmer I'm now testing on a freshly installed Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, arguably the current standard setup, and still having the problem. Could you please tell what exactly you used? Did you heed each of the points for reproduction?

Comment: I am using F# 3.1 on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a bug. I reported it and it was fixed on 2015-01-30 by Andrew Kennedy; [see this issue report for Visual F# on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/30).

Funny side-effect: the absurd code from this question ended up as a regression test. *(It is hereby public domain, just in case)*

**Future releases of F# should no longer have this issue.** Thanks to everyone who helped reproduce, analyze, and repair it!